# How to find a function which has bouned variaion but is not absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

The whole problem is:
Find a function that is in Bounded variation(BV) but not in Absolutely Continuous(AC).
It's not too hard to find a function is in BV, but how do we prove a function is not AC?

Answer (score 1):

You can take Cantor function. See details here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: But I don't know how to show it's not absolutely continuous, what should it need to prove?